# cakephp paginate: data from different tables

Tags: cakephp

i have "PostsController" controller and in this controller i need get all user list.
So i need get data no from "Posts" DB table, bu from "Users".
In function I make this paginate:

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'user' => array(
    'limit' => 2,
    'order' => array(
        'user.id' => 'asc',
    ),
    'table' => 'users'
    ),
);

$users = $this->paginate('user');
$this->set('users', $users);
```

But always get empty result, why?
And show this error:

```
Warning (512): Controller::paginate() - can't find model user in controller PostsController [CORE\cake\libs\controller\controller.php, line 1106]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Model name have first letter capitalized, so try

```
$this->paginate = array(
'User' => array(
'limit' => 2,
'order' => array(
    'User.id' => 'asc',
),
'table' => 'users'
),
);

$users = $this->paginate('User');
$this->set('users', $users);
```